# How to insert and remove tags while maintaining siblings beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I am receiving a table in html and need to iterate through it to find a  tag with `rowspan` set. Once I find a cell with `rowspan=<a number>`, I need to insert a block of code:

```
<tr>
<th rowspan="14" >Words</th>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="text-align: center; height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="text-align: right; padding: 7px; min-width: 75px"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
</tr>\n
```

as the row above the current row. Then, I need to remove this `<th>` from the current row.

For example, this is the code I would be searching through:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe" style="border: 1px solid grey">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Records</th>
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>good</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- this is the code im looking for -->
      <th rowspan="13" valign="top">Reports</th>
      <!--  -->
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>bad</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>400.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>bad</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So, once I find the `<th>` with `rowspan`, I need to insert the block as the row above it and then remove the `<th>` from the current row. Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
for child in soup.tbody.descendants:
        if child.name == 'th':
            if 'rowspan' in child.attrs:
                new_row = <<that block from above>>
                crazy_tag = bs4.BeautifulSoup(new_row, 'html.parser')
                x = child.find_previous('tr')
                x.insert_before(crazy_tag)
                child.extract()
```

The output I am looking for is this:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe" style="border: 1px solid grey">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Records</th>
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>good</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="14" >Words</th>
      <td style="height: 30px;"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center; height: 30px;"></td>
      <td style="height: 30px;"></td>
      <td style="text-align: right; padding: 7px; min-width: 75px"></td>
      <td style="height: 30px;"></td>
      <td style="height: 30px;"></td>
      <td style="height: 30px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>bad</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>400.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>bad</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The good news is, my code does what I want, and I get the desired output. The bad news is, there are other things I have to do to this html before I'm done. After I do this operation and it continues looping through the descendants, the next iteration gives me None. I thought extract() kept the structure of the tree intact but it seems like either the block I am inserting or the line I am deleting is not preserving the tree structure. Any ideas?

My question basically boils down to: how do I insert some html into a beautiful soup object and extract a line without ruining the sibling relationships in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `.insert_before()`/`.extract()` you can use simple [`.replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<table border="1" class="dataframe" style="border: 1px solid grey">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Records</th>
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>good</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- this is the code im looking for -->
      <th rowspan="13" valign="top">Reports</th>
      <!--  -->
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>=</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>bad</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Worth</th>
      <td>is</td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>400.0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>bad</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>"""

snippet = """\
<tr>
<th rowspan="14" >Words</th>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="text-align: center; height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="text-align: right; padding: 7px; min-width: 75px"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

for th in soup.select("th[rowspan]"):
    th.replace_with(BeautifulSoup(snippet, "html.parser"))

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe" style="border: 1px solid grey">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Records</th>
<th>Worth</th>
<td>30</td>
<td>is</td>
<td>50</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>good</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<!-- this is the code im looking for -->
<tr>
<th rowspan="14">Words</th>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="text-align: center; height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="text-align: right; padding: 7px; min-width: 75px"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
<td style="height: 30px;"></td>
</tr>
<!-- -->
<th>Worth</th>
<td>30</td>
<td>=</td>
<td>40</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>bad</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Worth</th>
<td>is</td>
<td>44</td>
<td>400.0</td>
<td></td>
<td>bad</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This does work and I ended up just actually using this code AFTER I do all my other operations on the html. Thanks for making it simple!